# Potion Miscibility: does the DM choose the permanent effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, alchemy

In the [Potion Miscibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/treasure#PotionMiscibility) variant rule is the choice of permanent effects up to the DM?

The rules for rolling 100 on mixing potions is:

> Only one potion works, but its effect is permanent. **Choose the simplest effect to make permanent, or the one that seems the most fun.** For example, a potion of healing might increase the drinker’s hit point maximum by 4, or oil of etherealness might permanently trap the user in the Ethereal Plane. At your discretion, an appropriate spell, such as dispel magic or remove curse, might end this lasting effect.

But it doesn't specify who chooses, is it the player or the DM?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the dungeon master who decides the permanent effect.

The Dungeon Master's Guide is instructions to dungeon masters.

The introduction to the DMG says:

> It’s good to be the Dungeon Master! Not only do you get to tell fantastic stories about heroes, villains, monsters, and magic, but you also get to create the world in which these stories live. Whether you’re running a D&D game already or you think it’s something you want to try, these rules are for you.

It is the DM who decides the permanent effects of the potion.  A smart DM is looking out for what is most fun for everyone.  And you can certainly discuss with the DM what you think the most fun outcome is.

It can be a little confusing because the audience shifts a bit in some of the DMG.  In the magic item descriptions, the audience is no longer the DM, it's the character.  The potion of healing says "You regain hit points...".  Obviously the "you" is the user of the potion, in other words, the creature drinking the potion.  However, in the overall book the "you" is the DM.

Comment: I'm the DM so that is the answer I wanted, thanks! I had been confused by the switching of wording, for example one of the other effects in the same table specifies "The mixture becomes an ingested poison of **the DM’s choice.**"  and this one just said "choose".